# Как удалить узел из DOM

Tags: javascript

Может тут кто-то подскажет решение проблемы? Пишу просто туду лист через классы, и не могу запустить метод `deleteTask`, т.к не знаю как его закрепить к кнопке `btn`

```
class ToDo {
    constructor({inputTask, addTask, finishedTask}) {
        this.inputTask = inputTask;
        this.addTask = addTask;
        this.finishedTask = finishedTask;

        addTask.onclick = () => this.add();

        var less = this.finishedTask.querySelectorAll('li').lastChild
        less.onclick = () => this.deleteTask();

    }

    createTask(task) {
        let listItem = document.createElement('li');
        let spanTask = document.createElement('span')
        spanTask.className = "text"
        spanTask.innerHTML = task;

        let btn = document.createElement('button')
        btn.classList = 'btnDelete'
        btn.innerHTML = 'delete'

        listItem.appendChild(spanTask);
        listItem.appendChild(btn);

        return listItem;
    }

    add() {
        if(this.inputTask.value) {
            let listItem = this.createTask(this.inputTask.value)
            this.finishedTask.appendChild(listItem)
            this.inputTask.value = '';
        }
    }

    deleteTask() {
        let listItem = this.parentNode;
        let ul = listItem.parentNode;
        ul.removeChild(listItem)
    }
}

let todo = new ToDo ({
    inputTask: document.getElementById('new-task'),
    addTask: document.getElementById('add'),
    finishedTask: document.getElementById('unfinished-tasks')
})
```

Comment: this.parentNode - это что у вас?

Comment: @Sublihim, это потеря контекста :-)

Comment: оказывается я ещё не правильно метод написал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном коде уже добавляется один обработчик `click`, для элемента

```
 var less = this.finishedTask.querySelectorAll('li').lastChild
```

Тот же подход надо было использовать применительно к создаваемой кнопке:

```
let btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.classList = 'btnDelete';
btn.innerHTML = 'delete';
btn.onclick = this.deleteTask;
```

Comment: спасибо, всё заработало, просто в методе createTask добавил  btn.onclick = this.deleteTask;

Comment: @Neuro, об этом в ответ как раз и написано :-)